# Using polar projections QGIS issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, basemap

I am wanting to project a basemap focusing on the Arctic. Currently I am using QuickMap Services / XYZ tiles as the basemap and projecting the map to EPSG:3995 WGS 84 / Arctic Polar Stereographic. However doing this causes a large hole in the centre of the Arctic ocean - how can I work around this to display the ocean seamlessly?
[image]

Comment: You need to find a base map that is not projected in EPSG:3857 as they stop at 85N/S leaving a hole

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to cover the poles with the Web Mercator coordinate system http://epsg.io/3857. By definition the area of use for that CRS is

`Area of use: World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N.`

You must acquire base maps from some other source. I don't know what maps this site is using https://geoportal.arctic-sdi.org/ but you can try to connect them.

[image]